# Using splice to delete item in array

Tags: javascript

Why does the remaining in original array = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

Since arr.splice(i, 1) = i is the target index and 1 is the number of item to be removed, i is increases to 10 respectively from i++ which short for i = i + 1, So why does it remove 5 index and remain 5 in the array ? that's what i know so far and i have struggled to read the docs but still have no idea to understand, please explain it for me

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

for(let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr.splice(i, 1);

}
```

Comment: I would reword your description of the question and tell what is your desired output.. After the code block you provided is ran, the remaining elements in the array are `2,4,6,8,10`

Comment: @codeherk yeah you're right i wrote it wrong there, it suppose to be let i = 1 in loop to get the array left = [1,3,5,7,9] but my question is still the same could you please explain why after this cod ran the original array remain ```[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]``` and the removed item from the array = ```[2,4,6,8,10]```

Comment: do you want to know why it's not recommended to alter an array that you're iterating over, or do you want help with what you're actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the length of arr decreases everytime splice function runs.
Here is how the array changes.

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

So every loop, i increases and arr.length decreases by 1. so only 5 loops runs and the result is [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining on the point exactly where i need, now it completely clear. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're wondering why it's removing 1, 3, 5, 7, and 9, right?

Here's why. As the for loop iterates, `i` keeps increasing by one.
HOWEVER, by calling `.splice`, you are removing the first element of the array, so as a result, every other element moves down an index.

Let's play this out step by step for a few iterations of the for loop.

i = 0; `arr.splice(0, 1)` removes 1, so `arr` is `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

i = 1; `arr.splice(1, 1)` removes **3**, not 2, because now 3 is at index 1 of `arr`. Performing the splice leaves `arr` as `[2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`.

i = 2; `arr.splice(2, 1)` removes 5, because 5 is currently at index 2. As a result, `arr` becomes `[2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`.

Is it clear now what's going on?

If your goal is to successively remove each element, one at a time, then instead of calling `.splice(i, 1)` in each iteration of the loop, you should call `.splice(0, 1)`, since the value at index 0 changes each time you call `.splice`.

Comment: why does it remove [2,4,6,8,10] from the arr and remain [1,3,5,7,9] ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the for loop end condition, i is not increasing to 10. Why? because i < arr.length.
So it will like this :

Iteration 1:

```
i=0; arr.length = 10; arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; ==> result [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

Iteration 2:

```
i=1; arr.length = 9; arr = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];  ==> result [2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

Iteration 3:

```
i=2; arr.length = 8; arr = [2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];  ==> result [2,4,6,7,8,9,10];
```

.
.
.and so forth

```
i = 5 ==> arr.length: 5 ==> final result : [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

So if you want to delete all items using splice:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

while(arr.length > 0) {

    arr.splice(0, 1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember, arrays are 0 based. Second, the length is changing each time it evaluates.

MDN links:

[Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

So you may want to try

`i =< length`

Where length is determined and is set ahead of time and constant. You can try mapping the array to a new one, so the original array stays pure and unaffected by the splice.